# Clickarea of Burger-Button is not fixed to actual Buttonarea

Tags: html, css, button, menu, nav

I don't understand the click area of my menu button.
I have colored green this time for testing purposes, so that the problem is immediately apparent.
Why is the background so distorted from the actual button?
How can I center it vertically?

You have to reduce the browser >920px to use the mobile version.

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(1.3em + 1vw)
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* header */

.header {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  background: #ffb347;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */ 
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #000;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.0em;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.header .logo:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  background: green;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 40px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 15px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -15px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 100%;

}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 920px) {
  .header .logo {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.3em;

}
  .header {
    position: relative;
  }
  .header li {
    float: left;   
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    line-height: 2.8em;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="" class="logo">LOREM <b>IPSUM</b></a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Set</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Amit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: I did now:  top: 0.3em;  right: 0.1em;  padding: 0.9em 0.4em; to ".header .menu-icon" and it's look ok. But it's absolutly weird to center this vertical ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going on:
The header height is calculated automatically according to paddings and vertical text size of "LOREN IPSUM". The label does not know that and you have to add after (or instead of) background: green one of the following

```
height: calc(1em + 16px);
padding-bottom: calc(1.2em + 3.5px);
```

Pixel adjustments are unintuitive and I would set the explicit height to header in em, and do the same for the label.

Comment: @Tisire: right. Then assigning height to the header is out. Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your label.

> style="width:20px;height:43px"

This will zoom in the clickable area.

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(1.3em + 1vw)
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* header */

.header {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  background: #ffb347;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */ 
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #000;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.0em;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.header .logo:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  background: green;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 40px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 15px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -15px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 100%;

}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 920px) {
  .header .logo {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.3em;

}
  .header {
    position: relative;
  }
  .header li {
    float: left;   
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    line-height: 2.8em;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/1.2.2/bluebird.js"></script>
 
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a href="" class="logo">LOREM <b>IPSUM</b></a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label style="width:20px;height:43px" class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work">Lorem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#careers">Dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Set</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Amit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```